# Caching dimension and attribute details

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, caching, enterprise-library, ssas-2008

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and use ADOMD class to get the dimension names and attribute names. This is a heavy operation and multiple users are using this application.

I am wondering which is the best caching technique I can use? **I want to create a dependency on SSAS cube. If cube is updated, I want to invalidate the cache.**

Since I am using .net framework 4.0, i can also use System.Runtime.Caching

Possible options:
 1. System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache 
 2. Enterprise library
 3. System.Runtime.Caching

please suggest the best caching library.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Runtime.Caching` is the defacto standard for caching. `Enterprise library` could be a little heavy for this kind of task but also worth exploring.